# Strange log rotation using logrotate file

Tags: logrotate

I have setup log rotation for postfix with a logrotate config file as follows:

```
/var/log/mail.*
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
}
```

But the files are rotating strangely.  For example, here is an excerpt of the mail log files I see:

```
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 10 01:47 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 11 02:04 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.2.gz.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 11 02:04 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.2.gz.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 19 01:48 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.2.gz.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 21 01:59 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.2.gz.1.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 23 02:16 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.2.gz.1.1.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 28 02:39 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.2.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm           20 Jan  8 01:36 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.2.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan  5 01:28 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.2.gz.1.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan  9 01:44 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.2.gz.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 10 01:47 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.3.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan  7 01:32 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.3.gz.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 11 02:04 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.4.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan  9 01:44 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.4.gz.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 19 01:48 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.5.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 21 01:59 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.5.gz.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 23 02:16 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.5.gz.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 28 02:39 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.5.gz.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm           33 Dec 31 01:25 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.5.gz.1.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan  9 01:44 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 10 01:47 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 10 01:47 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 12 02:26 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 20 01:51 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 22 02:06 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.1.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 24 02:26 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm           20 Jan  7 01:32 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan  5 01:28 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 11 02:04 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 19 01:48 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 21 01:59 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 23 02:16 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 28 02:39 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm           20 Jan  8 01:36 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.1.1.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan  9 01:44 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.3.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan  6 01:29 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.3.gz.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 10 01:47 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.4.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan  8 01:36 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.4.gz.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 12 02:26 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.5.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 20 01:51 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.5.gz.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 22 02:06 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.5.gz.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm            0 Jan 24 02:26 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.5.gz.1.1.1
-rw-r-----  1 syslog  adm           20 Jan  3 01:26 mail.log.7.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.2.gz.5.gz.1.1.1.1
```

Can someone explain what's wrong / what I need to add to my logrotate config file for postfix to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/var/log/mail.*`  matches all files starting with `mail.` including files that have already been rorated...

The only file that actually needs rotating is the current log file so please use `/var/log/mail.log` instead.